# Globally Lipschitz if and only if derivative is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, lipschitz-functions

If I have a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^n$ I can say that it is globally Lipschitz in $t$ if its Jacobian is bounded in $t$.

However, does it work the other way around? If I find that the function Jacobian is **not** bounded, does this mean that the function is **not** globally Lipschitz?

Comment: Yes, but that works only if $f$ is differentiable, while being Lipschitz or not is well defined for any function.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Could you explain what you mean by this please? Thanks!

Comment: You already know the answer for $n=1$.   Such functions are differentiable almost everywhere (not everywhere) and, even if they have a bounded derivative almost everywhere that wouldn't imply a Lipschitz condition.  Why would things get better for any other $n$?

Comment: Well, the notion of "Jacobian" is not defined for non-differentiable functions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function with unbounded derivative is not Lipschitz. Indeed, if $f'$ is unbounded, then for every $M$ there is $x$ such that $\|f'(x)\|>M$. By the definition of derivative (used with $\epsilon = \|f'(x)\|-M$, there is $h\ne 0$ such that 
$$\left\|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right\|>M $$
The inequality $\|f(x+h)-f(x)\|>M|h|$ shows that $f$ is not  Lipschitz with constant $M$. And since $M$ is arbitrary, it's not Lipschitz.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for this :)